# outputting valid Javascript from Java

Tags: java, javascript

I'm using Java 6.  I want to output code for a Javascript variable ...

```
                    String jsValue = escapeForJS(value);
                    String expression = "storedVars['myVar'] = \"" + jsValue + "\";";
```

Is there anything standard that will do this?  I came up with my own
function, but would prefer to use something tried and true.

```
    /* creates a JS expression that can be used within quotes. */
    private String escapeForJS(String value) {
            value = value.replace("\n", "\\n");
            value = value.replace("\r", "\\r");
            value = value.replace("\"", "\\\"");
            return value;
    }
```

- Dave

Comment: You'd probably want to escape \ to \\ also.

Comment: You also have to worry about embedded backslashes, and about Unicode characters out of the 7-bit range, and about non-printing control characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use JsonObject, should do exactly what you need.

Comment: But the Javascript variable I'm creating is not an object -- it is just a string.  How would I use JsonObject to do what I need?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JsonObject if you're happy to have the variables in JSON format.

Otherwise, There's no reason to escape anything other than double quotes, except for multi-line strings, the notation is a `\` at the end of the line, e.g.

```
var multilineString = "This is a \
                       multi-line string"
```

And be careful with single quotes and double quotes, Javascript can use either.